# How do i make the last char red in input placeholder?

Tags: css, sass

This is my input field [image], i want to change the last char '*' to be red instead of transparent black.

I have tried a lot of different approaches but none of them works, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simple, you can't. The only way is to create a custom input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the placeholder another color using the `::placeholder` selector. However, to give only one letter another color is not possible.

You can achieve what you want by creating a *custom input* element, using `HTML` and `CSS`.

```css
/**
 * Just a basic idea of how you can achieve what you want using HTML and CSS only.
 */

.input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

input {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ccc;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

/* Add the asterix when the input is required */
input:required + .placeholder::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}

/* Hide the placeholder when the user wants to fill the input */
input:focus + .placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" name="name" required />
  <span class="placeholder">Your name</span>
</div>
```

Remove the `placeholder=""` from your `input` and place the text inside the custom `span` element with the *classname placeholder*.

When the `input` is *required* the `CSS` will append a *asterix*.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let placeholder = document.getElementsByClassName('placeholder')[0];
placeholder.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.target.style.display="none";
    document.querySelector('input').focus();
    }
);
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focusout',(e)=>{
    if(e.target.value == ''){
        placeholder.style.display = 'inline';
    }
})
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus',(e)=>{
    if(e.target.value == ''){
        placeholder.style.display = 'none';
    }
})
```

```css
    .input{
    position: relative;
}
.placeholder{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 2px;
    user-select: none;
}
.placeholder::after{
    content: ' *';
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text">
        <span class="placeholder" >Your PlaceHolder</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).